# Splitting a primitive triangle into smaller triangles

Tags: c#, wpf, tessellation, helix-3d-toolkit

I am rendering a pipe using WPF with the Helix Toolkit. I realised that the function provided generates triangle primitives that are too large for my use.

[image]

For example, if the red triangle is my primitive, I want control over (say) the middle part of the triangle. One way I can think of is to further split the red triangle, into the blue triangles as shown. Could anyone point me to a method or algorithm that allows this split?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public struct Triangle
    {
        public Vector3 point1;
        public Vector3 point2;
        public Vector3 point3;

        public Triangle(Vector3 p1, Vector3 p2, Vector3 p3)
        { 
            this.point1 = p1;
            this.point2 = p2;
            this.point3 = p3; 
        }
    }

    public static Vector3 getMiddlePoint(Vector3 point1, Vector3 point2)
    {
        return new Vector3((point1.X + point2.X) / 2.0f, (point1.Y + point2.Y) / 2.0f, (point1.Z + point2.Z) / 2.0f);
    }

    public static List<Triangle> SplitTriangle(Triangle tri)
    {
        Vector3 a = getMiddlePoint(tri.point1, tri.point2);      
        Vector3 b = getMiddlePoint(tri.point2, tri.point3);
        Vector3 c = getMiddlePoint(tri.point3, tri.point1);
        List<Triangle> NewTris = new List<Triangle>();
        NewTris.Add(new Triangle(tri.point1, a, c));
        NewTris.Add(new Triangle(tri.point2, b, a));
        NewTris.Add(new Triangle(tri.point3, c, b));
        NewTris.Add(new Triangle(a, b, c);
        return NewTris;
    }
```